# Looking for a character like the greek theta, θ, but with two middle lines

Tags: writing-systems

I'm looking for a character in any writing system or even a known symbol (more common is better) that would roughly look like the Greek theta θ, but with two lines in the middle.

If there is none, it could also be similar to an H, but with two middle lines.

Anything like that out there? I've been scrolling through the unicode list, but could not find anything like there.

Comment: I am not aware of two lines. Linear B "qe" is the closest you will get, but it's more like two double dashes after each other in two rows.

Comment: What is your motivation for asking this? Have you seen such a character in real life, or do you want to introduce some new character into mathematical notation?

Answer (score 2):

For the "theta with two middle lines", [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) recommends GURMUKHI URA ੳ. You can also use a normal theta plus a combining stroke character: θ̶ or θ̵.

For an "H with two middle lines", try the letter Barred H (or H With Stroke as Unicode calls it): capital Ħ, lowercase ħ. It's used in some languages to represent an epiglottal or pharyngeal fricative, but the lowercase is better-known from physics.

Comment: "Some languages". I know it from Maltese. Are there any others?

Comment: @fdb Some Semitic transcriptions use it for IPA `/ħ/` since it looks more distinct than `ḥ`; I've seen it used that way for Egyptian, Arabic, and Hebrew. I'm not sure if it's official anywhere except Maltese.

Comment: You can also use two box drawing characters to make a double H: ╞╡

Answer (score 1):

Both of those letters did at one time contain two interior lines.

Heta (the consonantal Eta) is traced back to ancient Egyptian, where it looked like a fence.  Multiple 'pickets' remained through Phonecian, archaic Greek, and Etruscan.  {The unicode?? is called Greek_Eta_2-bars.}  Some versions have slanted pickets.

Theta started out containing a cross (+ or X) (sorry, not =).  Some variants contain just a dot or isolated dash.

Comment: `Greek_Eta_2-bars` is the name of the SVG file on Wikipedia, but I don't believe it has a Unicode codepoint (it's considered a glyph variant).

Comment: Thank you - I am lost in the technical weeds and don't expect to escape, but appreciate anyone lighting the way.